# LINQ beginner, table joining query for document version

Tags: linq

I have a `Document` table and a `Version` table.  Both have identical information.  Whenever a document is created it is inserted into the document table.  Whenever that document is then edited a line is added to the Versions table.

It has a field dateApproved which will be `null` until it is approved.  I am currently working on a MVC 4 Approval page and I have never touched linq before and it needs to be done in linq.

How can I join these two tables Document/Version and only show items where dateApproved is `null`?

```
from v in Versions
select v

from v in Document
select v
```

EDIT #1

A user adds a brand new document, this document is then added to the document table.  At this point the document needs approval.  The dateApproved field in the Documents table is null.  Lets say this document gets approved, then the user makes a change and since this document already exists a line is added to the Versions table.  Now this document exists in both tables the original document having a revision 0 with a dateApproved, and the Versions table have a revision 1 with a dateApproved as null.

What I need is the documents where the dateApproved is null weather this null is in the Documents table or the Versions table.  After it is approved we leave the line in the Version table, and update the line in the Documents table with the approved version.

The key primary key is DocumentID.

EDIT #2

Thanks to Peter Kiss it is now displaying all the files that need to be approved.  There is one more hiccup I am running into.  It is returning 3 results which is correct.  2 files are brand new and 1 has been edited.

The 2 brand new files it displays the information correctly as from the documents table.  The edited file it is displaying the information from the documents table but I need the info from the revisions table.  Is it possible to make it return the version table information if the item exists in the version table and return the document table information if it does not exist in the version table (ie brand new).

Hope I explained that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var documents = 
    ctx.Documents
         .Where(x => x.dateApproved == null 
                     || x.Versions.Any
                           (y => y.dateApproved == null));
```

The documents variable will contain only those documents which are having unapproved versions. Then when you iterating through this collection the current document can reach it's Versions (all) through a navigation property called Versions. In that collection you can filter the unapproved versions.

All this only happens when the mapping is set up correctly (aka foreign keys) in your context.

### After Edit #2

```
class DocumentToApprove
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* other stuff */
    public int version { get; set; }
}

var documents = ctx.Documents
          .Where(x => x.dateApproved == null 
                      || x.Versions.Any(y => y.dateApproved == null));

var toApprove = from d in documents
            let v = d.Versions.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Approved == null)
        select new DocumentToApprove
                   {    Name = d.Name
                                ,
                                /* other stuff */
                                Version = v == null ? 1 : v.VersionNumber
                            };
```

Comment: hrm, it is giving the following error.  The name 'ctx' does not exist in the current context I'm a complete novice to Linq.

Comment: I changed it to this, again I have never touched linq until just now.  Let me know if this will not work, it runs successfully, but now I am stuck on how to get it to display in LinqPad, it just runs, but shows nothing I assume because im not looking through the `documents` variable, but not sure how in LinqPad.  `var document = Documents.Where(x => x.Versions.Any(y => y.DateApproved == null));`

Comment: Could not get this method to work.  It seems to only be showing the item if it is in both tables.  I just crated a new document, it has a line only in the document table and it won't show up in the query.  However the other un-approved item shows up that has a line in both tables.

Comment: !x.Versions.Any() || needed in the Where see my post (i've just edited).

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, I wish I understood Linq better.  this version is listing documents that don't need to be approved.  It correctly lists the documents that do need to be approved, but it is listing 3 documents that have been approved.  I made an edit to the original post to provide a better explanation.  I thank you in advance for the extra time spent, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Made an edit to my answer again i think this will be the one you are looking for.

Comment: It is correctly returning the 3 items needed for approval now, however I ran into one more hiccup, I updated the original post.  Let me know if you can think of anything, I'll keep trying things on this end as well.  Appreciate all your help!

Comment: Thank you for the update, I have it 99% working now.  But upon loading the page it is giving me an error: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery 1[IPACS.Controllers.DocumentController+DocumentToApprove]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[IPACS.Models.IPACS_Document]'.`  Instead of passing the original docs object to the view I am now passing your `toApprove` to the view. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Select only records which are having `dateApproved` is null. and collect it in some kind of list `listofVersions`.

```
var listofVersions=(from v in Versions 
         where v.dateApproved==null
         select v).ToList();
```

You can do the same for `Document`. Just substitute `Version` with `Document`.
Note: I just collect it with `var` to make it simple. You  can create a list of `Versions/Document` if you wish.

Comment: Is there no way to join them, so I get one list which searches both Version and Document?

Comment: There is. Just clarify how you want to join it.

Comment: For example, you can do like this

var list=(from v in Versions join d in Document on v.dateApproved equals d.dateApproved where v.dateApprove==null
select v).ToList();

Comment: A line will always be in the document table.  Whenever a document is uploaded we add a line.  Then if that document is ever modified, we add a line into the Version table.  So I need a list of all documents that have not been approved `where dateApproved != null`.  I should be able to fumble through the rest of my requirements if I can get that portion working.

Comment: The key id docId.  Those will be the same in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to get it to work from your last comment. :)